# How to iterate over list which contains whitespaces in bash

Tags: bash, loops

Could you please tell me how to iterate over list where items can contain whitespaces?

```
x=("some word", "other word", "third word")
for word in $x ; do
    echo -e "$word\n"
done
```

how to force it to output:

```
some word
other word
third word
```

instead of:

```
some
word
(...)
third
word
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To loop through items properly you need to use `${var[@]}`. And you need to quote it to make sure that the items with spaces are not split: `"${var[@]}"`.

All together:

```
x=("some word" "other word" "third word")
for word in "${x[@]}" ; do
  echo -e "$word\n"
done
```

Or, saner ([thanks Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587972/how-to-iterate-over-list-which-contains-whitespaces-in-bash/14588210#comment48184385_14588210)) with `printf`:

```
x=("some word" "other word" "third word")
for word in "${x[@]}" ; do
  printf '%s\n\n' "$word"
done
```

Comment: you may want to `set -f` to turn globbing off. Please see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/set

Comment: @cravoori: that's not necessary as long as all references to the variable(s) are in double-quotes -- which they are.

Comment: `echo -e`? If what the OP really wants is an extra newline on the end, `printf '%s\n\n'` would be saner.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions, one similar to fedorqui's solution, without the extra ',', and another using array indexing:

```
x=( 'some word' 'other word' 'third word')

# Use array indexing
let len=${#x[@]}-1
for i in $(seq 0 $len); do
        echo -e "${x[i]}"
done

# Use array expansion
for word in "${x[@]}" ; do
  echo -e "$word"
done
```

Output:

```
some word
other word
third word
some word
other word
third word
```

**edit:** fixed issues with the indexed solution as pointed out by [cravoori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753731/cravoori)

Comment: your array indexing solution is bogus. It prints 3 array members regardless of array length. You need to put `seq` inside a `command substitution`. Also, start with 0 instead of 1