# How to process each output line in a loop?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a number of lines retrieved from a file after running the [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) command as follows:

```
var=`grep xyz abc.txt`
```

Let’s say I got 10 lines which consists of xyz as a result.

Now I need to process each line I got as a result of the grep command. How do I proceed for this?

Comment: None of the answers here mention the power of `grep -o` for this sort of thing.  The `-o` flag will give back _only_ the text that matches, with one match per line of output.  (It's not exhaustive, so `echo aaa |grep 'a*'` only gives you "aaa" and omits the three partial matches "", "a", and "aa")

Answer (score 348, accepted):

One of the easy ways is not to store the output in a variable, but directly iterate over it with a while/read loop.

Something like:

```
grep xyz abc.txt | while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
    # your code goes here
done
```

There are variations on this scheme depending on exactly what you're after.

If you need to change variables inside the loop (and have that change be visible outside of it), you can use process substitution as stated in [fedorqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16318041/1983854):

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
    # your code goes here
done < <(grep xyz abc.txt)
```

Comment: if there is no line with xyz  ?

Comment: Then nothing happens, the loop is not run.

Comment: The problem with this method is that (because of the pipe) everything inside the loop is in a subshell, so setting variables defined outside the loop during the loop does not make their values available after the loop!

Comment: @David: provided an alternative to address your concern. (fedorqui had already addressed it too.)

Comment: For commands whose last line of output is not terminated with a newline, you'd need: `while read p || [[ -n $p ]]; do ...` (borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash#comment31060693_1521498)

Comment: it seems that both of these solutions disable color in whatever is run inside the loop.. is this solvable somehow?

Comment: I also added `--line-buffered` to my grep command on MacOSX, as this version of grep seems to buffer it's output, meaning that I did not see the output streaming

Answer (score 28):

You can do the following `while read` loop, that will be fed by the result of the `grep` command using the so called process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -r result
do
    #whatever with value $result
done < <(grep "xyz" abc.txt)
```

This way, you don't have to store the result in a variable, but directly "inject" its output to the loop.

---

Note the usage of `IFS=` and `read -r` according to the recommendations in BashFAQ/001: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

> The -r option to read prevents backslash interpretation (usually used
>   as a backslash newline pair, to continue over multiple lines or to
>   escape the delimiters). Without this option, any unescaped backslashes
>   in the input will be discarded. You should almost always use the -r
>   option with read.
>
> In the scenario above IFS= prevents trimming of leading and trailing
>   whitespace. Remove it if you want this effect.

Regarding the process substitution, it is explained in the [bash hackers page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

> Process substitution is a form of redirection where the input or
>   output of a process (some sequence of commands) appear as a temporary
>   file.

Comment: OK, I striked the `for` version. Tried to do a loop on `"${$(grep xyz abc.txt)[@]}"` as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14588210/1983854 but could not. So I just leave the first version.

Comment: You can't apply parameter expansion to a command substitution (unless you're using `zsh`, where that kind of nesting probably works).

Comment: One possible problem with this idiom is that if anything inside the loop tries to read from standard input, it'll get part of the file. To avoid this possibility, I like to send the file through file descriptor 3 rather than stdin. Just use `while IFS= read -r result <&3` and `done 3< <(grep ...`

Comment: I know the original question asked for bash, but for future readers: this is not POSIX-compliant. shellcheck(SC2039): In POSIX sh, process substitution is undefined.

Answer (score 23):

For those looking for a one-liner:

```
grep xyz abc.txt | while read -r line; do echo "Processing $line"; done
```

Comment: rly needed this thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using awk instead of grep + something else here.

`awk '$0~/xyz/{ //your code goes here}' abc.txt`

Comment: How would you reference the complete found line in `//your code goes here`?

Comment: @user857990 The whole line is represented as $0 in AWK.

Answer (score 2):

Without any iteration with the --line-buffered grep option:

```
your_command | grep --line-buffered "your search"
```

Real life exemple with a Symfony PHP Framework router debug command ouput, to grep all "api" related routes:

```
php bin/console d:r | grep --line-buffered "api"
```

Comment: The only solution that works if your_command is long-running (such as `tail -f some.log`, in my case)...

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the grep results with a while/read loop.
Like:

```
grep pattern filename.txt | while read -r line ; do
    echo "Matched Line:  $line"
    # your code goes here
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Often the order of the processing does not matter. GNU Parallel is made for this situation:

```
grep xyz abc.txt | parallel echo do stuff to {}
```

If you processing is more like:

```
grep xyz abc.txt | myprogram_reading_from_stdin
```

and `myprogram` is slow then you can run:

```
grep xyz abc.txt | parallel --pipe myprogram_reading_from_stdin
```