# Search in CSV file and split each matching line using command-line tools

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm using the following command:

```
grep -F "searchterm" source.csv >> output.csv
```

to search for matching terms in `source.csv`.  Each line in the source file is like so:

> ```
> value1,value2,value3|value4,value5
> ```

How do I insert only the fields `value1,value2,value3` into the output file?

Comment: Looks like you trailed off there... Missing the end of your last sentence.

Comment: It's unclear what you want.  Do you want _search_ first then _split_?  What is the goal of the search?

Comment: ... into the output file. Sorry, the site was acting up.

Comment: `grep ... | cut -d'|' -f1 >> output.csv`  Is this what you want?

Comment: I want to search, then split the resulting line and input that into the output.csv file.

Comment: Looks like Cong Ma's solution works great, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to append some text to the value being inserted into the output file? So something like NEWvalue,value1,value2,value3?

Comment: `man 1 paste` (padding to pass SO's bullshit filter).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `awk` which will go through line by line and then you apply the separator and get the part you would like to take from the string .

`awk -F"|" '{print $1}' input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: Use of `cat` is redundant here.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but how is this applied with the grep functionality?

Comment: Not a silly question at all, but `grep` mainly is a tool to check for occurrences of a string with a matching pattern, `awk` on the other side is built for text processing. I would check this link for the purpose of using grep. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317961/how-to-process-each-line-received-as-a-result-of-grep-command

Comment: Ah ok. So I would be looking for something like this?

grep -F "searchterm" filetosearch.txt | awk -F"|" '{print $1}' input.txt > output.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple `while read` loop:

```
while read -r line; do echo ${line%|*}; done < file.csv >> newfile.csv
```

or in a subshell, so you truncate the newfile each time:

```
( while read -r line; do echo ${line%|*}; done < file.csv ) > newfile.csv
```

or with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/[|].*$//' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This perl solution is similar to the awk solution:

`perl -F'\|' -lane 'print $F[0]' input.csv > output.csv`

The `|` field separator character needs to be escaped with a `\`

`-a` puts perl into autosplit mode, which populates the fields array `F`