# shell, pipe a list of arguments one by one to command

Tags: shell, awk, pipe, command-line-arguments

I have a list  arguments needed to be passed one by one to another command, since  the command only accepts one argument at time, any shell pipe I can use? Thank you in advance.

For example,

```
$ ls -al | awk '{print $9}'
```

the command will return a list of folder names, then I need send these names as arguement to anther command, which only accepts on command per execution.

Comment: This may be related: [how to process each line received as a result of grep command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16317961/1627585)

Comment: try to do it in one command line, any idea?

Comment: You should avoid parsing output of `ls`. Can you provide more details what you're trying to do here?

Comment: Have you looked at `xargs` for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand the `ls -al | awk ...` analogy. What is the point of including this code example?

If you have a whitespace delimited list of arguments, using a utility command like `xargs` will supply each argument to a command one-by-one by default. You can change this default behavior, but it doesn't seem like that you'd need to. You can use `xargs` as follows...

```
ls -al | awk '{print $9}' | xargs cat
```

...to `cat` the contents of each file output by the `ls -al` command. Does this help?

It should be noted though that `ls` is a porcelain command and not a plumbing command. In other words, it is best practice to not rely on the output of `ls` for a command pipeline. A utility like `find`, however, is a plumbing command and is preferable to use as a part of a pipeline.

Comment: You may want/need to add `-L 1` to your `xargs` command depending on the output format of whatever your first command is.

Comment: Of course, `cat .[!.]* *` works much better.  In particular, the Awk will munge any filename which contains whitespace, which the plain wildcard expansion will not.

Comment: with `xargs -L 1 cat`, give me the right output, as the list is line separated. Thx a lot

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of "porcelain" and "plumbing" commands before. But at least found some info on the net. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec your_command {} \;
```

This will call `your_command` for any folder in the current directory expect of `.` and `..`

Comment: This selects only directories, which seems to be anathema to what the OP asked for.

Comment: No, it just seems to be anathema to OP's unfinished command. He states: `... the command will return a list of folder names`. That makes me think that `your_command` will likely just accept folders.