# GREP by result of awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Output of awk '{print $4}' is

```
b05808aa-c6ad-4d30-a334-198ff5726f7c
59996d37-9008-4b3b-ab22-340955cb6019
2b41f358-ff6d-418c-a0d3-ac7151c03b78
7ac4995c-ff2c-4717-a2ac-e6870a5670f0
```

I need to grep file st.log by these records. Something like `awk '{print $4}' |xargs -i grep -w "pattern from awk" st.log` I dont know how to pass pattern correctly?

Comment: why can't you just use awk?

Comment: What is the structure of `st.log`? Some representative sample lines would help. If the GUIDs are always in a specific field, then the awk script could be made more efficient.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we're not guessing at what you're asking for help with. Right now we don't even know if you're running the awk command on `st.log`, same as your grep command, or something else which greatly impacts the potential solutions. Nor do we know if your files are Terrabytes or 10 lines each which also has an impact. Your question is extremely unclear as written and doesn't lend itself to us helping you come up with a good solution.

Comment: Put your filter in `awk` so that only the requested elements are printed in the first place. `awk '$4 ~ /^b/ {print $4}`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
awk '{print $4}' | grep -F -f - st.log
```

Credits to Eric Renouf, who noticed that `-f -` can be used for standard input instead `-f <(cat)`, Note: `-f /dev/stdin` also works and avoids launching a new process.

or closer to the question to have the output ordered

```
awk '{print $4}' | xargs -i grep -F {} st.log
```

maybe `-w` was not the option OP needed but `-F`

```
grep --help
-F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings
-w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words
```

`-w` will match only line that contain exactly pattern

examples

```
grep -w . <<<a       # matches
grep -w . <<<ab      # doesn't match
grep -F . <<<a       # doesn't match
grep -F . <<<a.b     # matches
```

Comment: In addition to what Ed says, you needn't use a process substitution here either, `grep -w -f - st.log` would read the patterns from stdin without the `cat`

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't agree, using awk, grep and sed are simple operation to be pipelined, otherwise one could use a more powerful language like perl

Comment: @TomFenech But if it's reading the output of `awk` as here you already get it.  I'm just saying `grep -f -` is easier than `grep -f <(cat)`

Comment: @EricRenouf I tried what you suggest before and it didn't work

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul `awk '{print $4}' | grep -w -f - st.log` doesn't work?  What about it didn't work?

Comment: Also, if you are using the process substitution you also wouldn't need the pipe, you could do `grep -w -f <(awk '{print $4}' somefile) st.log`, if `awk` is reading from a file and not `stdin` itself

Comment: @EricRenouf which version of grep accept `-f -` do you have the reference ? `echo a | grep -f - <<<a` `echo a | grep -f <(cat) <<<a`

Comment: I've tested `-f -` with both GNU grep and BSD grep and had the expected results

Comment: I just tried the same `grep -f -` as you and used `strace` to figure out why your example doesn't work when using files actually does.  It seems the herestring and the pipe step on each other for becoming `stdin` so you end up reading the herestring as your pattern list and then have an empty stream to read for the search space, so it doesn't match anything.  Try the experiment again using actual files for the search space though and you should see it working as expected

Comment: @EricRenouf ok replacing `<<<a` by `<(echo a)` for my examples, i will update my answer

Comment: Why not just process-substitute the awk command?  Something like  `grep -F -f <(awk '...') st.log`, for example.  It may also be worth suggesting to write the `awk` output to a file, if it's to be used more than once.  As Ed says in the comment to the question, so much depends on the scale of the inputs and outputs.

Comment: You're right however here the answer answers just to the question

Answer (score -2):

May be something along these lines be helpful

[How to process each line received as a result of grep command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317961/how-to-process-each-line-received-as-a-result-of-grep-command)

```
awk '{print $4} | while read -r line; do 
    grep $line st.log
done
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is quite a bad solution since you fork a new grep process for every line. You also should quote your variables.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some, but not all, of the issues with your script.