# Linux find script result not appending to the output text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote small shell script, to identify the PDF file associate pages in my website.

It’s take the pdf source list url one by one, as an input and finding recursive in website content.

**Problem is when I run the script find result not appending to the output file,
But when I take the find command and run in terminal/putty manually can see the result.**

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="PDF_Search_File.txt"
while read -r line
do
        name="$line"
                echo "*******pdf******** - $name\n" >>output_pdf_new.txt
        find . -type f -exec grep -l "$name" '{}' \; >>output_pdf_new.txt
                echo "*******pdf******** - $name\n" >>output_pdf_new.txt
done < "$filename"
```

source list url input file (PDF_Search_File.txt)

```
/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf
/static/pdf/pdf2.pdf
/static/pdf/pdf3.pdf
--------------------
```

out put result file (output_pdf_new.txt)

```
./Search_pdf.sh
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf1.pdf\n
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf1.pdf\n
./Search_pdf.sh
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf2.pdf\n
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf2.pdf\n
./Search_pdf.sh
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf3.pdf\n
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf3.pdf\n
------------------------------------------
```

terminal/putty can see the result for below, when manually run the find.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf" '{}' \;

./en/toyes/zzz/index.xhtml
./en/toyes/kkk/index.xhtml
--------------
```

but having issue with script , only out put the echo result as above output result .

**Update** 
when i execute the script with bash -x , it's giving below result

```
[user@server1 generated_content]# bash -x Search_pdf.sh
+ filename=PDF_Search_File.txt
+ read -r line
+ name=$'/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf\r'
\n'cho '*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf1.pdf
+ find . -type f -exec grep -l $'/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf\r' '{}' ';'
\n'cho '*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf1.pdf
+ read -r line
+ name=$'/static/pdf/pdf2.pdf\r'
\n'cho '*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf2.pdf
+ find . -type f -exec grep -l $'/static/pdf/pdf2.pdf\r' '{}' ';'
```

is something wrong here

```
  + find . -type f -exec grep -l $'/static/pdf/pdf2.pdf\r' '{}' ';'
```

find command should be like below , but it's taking as above when executing

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf" '{}' \;
```

Comment: Are you in the same directory when you run the script as when you run the command by hand?

Comment: Yes It is , I was in same directory . also I'm running the script in same location

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so you can see all the commands as they're being executed, maybe you'll see something wrong there.

Comment: Put `ls ./en/toyes/*/index.xhtml` in the script. What does it show?

Comment: <a onClick="downloadEventCapture('/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf','Not Logged In','Products','Spain');" href="/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf"><img src="/static/assets/images/pdf.gif" alt="" /></a>
 <h4><a onClick="downloadEventCapture('/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf','Not Logged In','Products','Spain');"  href="/static/pdf/pdf1.pdf">Contact</a></h4>

Comment: That's the output of `ls`?

Comment: That looks more like the output of `cat` than `ls`.

Comment: You have `\r\n` line endings in `PDF_Search_File.txt`. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: Please find my Update in original question , it's seems to be when i tested using bach -x , getting wrong input ?

Comment: See my comment above -- fix the newlines in the file.

Comment: Stop using Windows to edit files for Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **-e** option in `echo` to enable interpretation of backslash escapes?

<strike>Also why don't you simply do `find | grep`?</strike>

<strike>find ./ -type f | grep "$name" >> output_pdf_new.txt</strike>

Try following (**./** instead of **.**) in find

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -l "$name" '{}' \; >>output_pdf_new.txt
```

Comment: echo result not having any issue , it's appending to the file , only find result not appending to the file.   please tell me where  i did wrong here

Comment: @chamara, edited answer with `find | grep` suggestion.

Comment: No above command ,not working brother  , i just want to find the website pages inside the  source  , where those pdf links , then out put should result is website page index.html url  my command working  successfully when i test manually in putty , but i have huge pdf list

Comment: `find | grep` matches the filenames, he wants to match the contents of the file.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. Your original find command should work though.

Answer (score 0):

grep -rl for the file inside of your for loop:

```
cd /www/webroot/
grep -rl "${name}" * | while read file_path; do
    # I need to do something with each file
    echo $file_path
done
```

OR I just need to run the output to file

```
cd /www/webroot/
grep -rl "${name}" * >> output_pdf_new.txt
```

Comment: Why do you need the `while` loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317961/how-to-process-each-line-received-as-a-result-of-grep-command

Comment: If you're just echoing it, you don't need a processing loop. Just redirect the output of `grep -rl`.

Comment: That question is about doing something with the output other than just echoing it.

Comment: CORRRECT. they can figure out what to do with the echo I hope ;-)

Comment: `grep -rl "${name}" * >> output_pdf_new.txt`

Comment: I know this, perhaps just giving them an option that they can work with more easily  etc ..