# Command substitution with strings in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to check which lines of the file /etc/passwd end with the "/bin/bash" string (field number 7, ":" as delimiter).
So far, I've written the following code:

```
while read line
do
    if [ $("$line" | cut -d : -f 7)=="/bin/bash" ]
    then
        echo $line | cut -d : -f 1
        echo "\n"
    fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

Currently, executing the script throws errors that show a bad interpretation (most likely due to the syntax).
I'd appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: I can't understand why so many people pounce on the umpteenth repeat of a problem with an answer rather than looking for a dupe or at least requesting that the error message be provided verbatim (which would make finding an actual dupe [or a solution, as it were]) much easier ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
if [ $("$line" | cut -d : -f 7)=="/bin/bash" ]
```

Also, this is not going to do what you want:

```
 echo "\n"
```

Bash echo doesn't understand backslash-escaped characters without
-e. If you want to print a new line use just `echo` but notice that
the previous echo:

```
echo $line | cut -d : -f 1
```

will add a newline already.

You should always check your scripts with
[shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). The correct script would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r line
do
    if [ "$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 7)" == "/bin/bash" ]
    then
        echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 1
    fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

But notice that you don't really need a loop which is very slow and
could use the following awk one-liner:

```
awk -v FS=: '$7 == "/bin/bash" {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: When trying your response, the first operator of the line line if [ "$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 7)" == "/bin/bash" ] is unexpected, as the terminal says. I'm kind of newbie to this, could you help me out?

Comment: Just copy my script exactly as it is and run it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I figured out that the mistake was writing == instead of =

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You MUST surround the `==` operator with spaces. `[` and `[[` do different things based on *how many arguments* are given:

```sh
if [ "$( echo "$line" | cut -d: -f7 )" == "/bin/bash" ]; ...
```

---

I would actually do this: parse the line into fields while you're reading it.

```sh
while IFS=: read -ra fields; do
    [[ ${fields[-1]} == "/bin/bash" ]] && printf "%s\n\n" "${fields[0]}"
done < /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the rows, and then checking for the `/bin/bash` part, why not use something like [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to get all the desired rows, like so:

```sh
grep ':/bin/bash$' /etc/passwd
```

Optionality, you can loop over the rows by using a [simple `while`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317961/how-to-process-each-output-line-in-a-loop);

```sh
grep ':/bin/bash$' /etc/passwd | while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
done
```

Comment: The loop doesn't really add any value here. Simply `grep ':/bin/bash$' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `while read | cut`.  Use IFS as:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS=: read name passwd uid gid gecos home shell; do
        if test "$shell" = /bin/bash; then
                echo "$name"
        fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

But for this particular use case, it's probably better to do:

```
awk '$7 == "/bin/bash"{print $1}' FS=: /etc/passwd
```

The issue your code has is a common error.  Consider the line:

```
if [ $("$line" | cut -d : -f 7)=="/bin/bash" ]
```

Assume you have a value in `$line` in which the final field is `/bin/dash`.  The process substitution will insert the string `/bin/dash`, and bash will attempt to execute:

```
if [ /bin/dash==/bin/bash ]
```

since `/bin/bash==/bin/bash` is a non-empty string, the command `[ /bin/bash==/bin/bash ]` returns succesfully.  It does *not* perform any sort of string comparison.  In order for `[` to do a string comparison, you need to pass it 4 arguments.  For example, `[ /bin/dash = /bin/bash ]` would fail.  Note the 4 arguments to that call are `/bin/dash`, `=`, `/bin/bash`, and `]`.  `[` is an incredibly bizarre command that requires its final argument to be `]`.  I strongly recommend never using it, and replacing it instead with its cousin `test` (very closely related, indeed both `test` and `[` used to be linked to the same executable) which behaves exactly the same but does not require its final argument to be `]`.