# Difference between $@ and $* in bash scripting

Tags: bash

I'm new in bash and I'm learning it, and I have a doubt about the real difference between the use of `$@` and `S*`.

I red here [Bash Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

I understand that both expand to the positional parameters, but the difference occurs within double quotes. 
By the way `"$@" = "$1" "$2"..."$n"` could be different than `"S*" = "$1$2...$n".`

I try to understand it with a simple script:

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
       echo "Your command line contains $# arguments" 
else
       echo "Your command line contains no arguments"
       exit  fi

echo "Params are: "
echo $@  
echo $* 
echo "$@"    
echo "$*"
```

if I execute my script in the terminal like this `~./my_script par1 par2 par3`

the result is always the same:

```
Params are:
par1 par2 par3
par1 par2 par3
par1 par2 par3
par1 par2 par3
```

Maybe I don't understand the real use of both special variables and If my example is correct or not. I'd like to figure out this point also with a good example.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-the-difference-between-and-in-bash

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry for duplicate question, but I'd like to understand also in my example.

Comment: The linked questions have pretty *detailed* explanations.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008734/2235132 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2761739/2235132 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14247889/2235132 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14247867/2235132

Comment: Tons of explanations! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html:

> "$*"  All the positional parameters (as a single word) *
>
> "$@"  All the positional parameters (as separate strings)

This code shows it: given a string with items separated by spaces, `$@` considers every word as a new item, while `$*` considers them all together the same parameter.

```
echo "Params for: \$@"
for item in "${@}"
do
        echo $item --
done

echo "Params for : \$*"
for item in "${*}"
do
        echo $item --
done
```

Test:

```
$ ./a par1 par2 par3
Your command line contains 3 arguments
Params for: $@
par1 --
par2 --
par3 --
Params for : $*
par1 par2 par3 --
```

Comment: So the use of echo in my example is not explicative to understand the differece.

Comment: Exactly, @Kyrol . You can get more proper information when looping in the variable to show which "pieces" it is getting.

Comment: Just another doubt: in this case there are differences between `"${@}"` and `"$@"`in the `for` loops that you used? I think is the same thing.

Comment: Yes, @Kyrol, `${var_name}` and `$var_name` are exactly the same. I put this one because I was checking my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14588210/1983854, where spaces did matter and where taken into account with `"${x[@]}"`.

Comment: I saw the question you answered. Thanks a lot for explanation again! ;)

Answer (score 4):

They may appear the same when you are using `echo` but this is due to them being treated the same by `echo` and not being equivalent.

If pass three command-line arguments given to a bash script to a C program using
 `./my_c $@`,

you get the result `ARGV[1] == "par1"` `ARGV[2] == "par2"` `ARGV[3] == "par3"`.

If you pass three command-line arguments given to a bash script to a C program using `./my_c $*`,

you get the result `ARGV[1] == "par1 par2 par3"`.

(`ARGV` is the array of supplied arguments in C, the first element is always the command-name the program was invoked with)

It's to allow greater flexibility with what you do with the given parameters later in the script.

Comment: Thanks for the C explanation.