# Bash grep function for strings in array, can't get the quotation marks correct

Tags: arrays, string, bash, function, grep

I'm trying to create a function that will do a grep on strings from an array that are sent as arguments but I can't get the quotation marks to work as I want.

> ```
> LOG=/tmp/log.log
> function grepCheck () {
>     if grep $1 ; then
>     STATE="true"
>     else
>     STATE="false"
>     fi }
>
> possibleErrors=("string1 string1 string1" "string2 string2 string2")
>
> for checkError in ${possibleErrors[*]}
> do
> grepCheck "${possibleErrors[$checkError]} $LOG"
> done
> ```

Output example:

```
+ LOG=/tmp/log.log
+ possibleErrors=("string1 string1 string1" "string2 string2 string2")
+ for checkError in '${possibleErrors[*]}'
+ grepCheck 'string1 string1 string1 /tmp/log.log'
+ grep string1 string1 string1 /tmp/log.log grep: string1: No such file or directory grep: string1: No such file or directory
```

How do I get the function to grep the string that it recieves?

Comment: Check: [How to iterate over list which contains whitespaces in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14588210/1983854)

Comment: Please, use [double quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes sense is for your function to accept the same arguments `grep` does.

```
LOG=/tmp/log.log
grepCheck () {
    # Edit: use "$@"; add -q option to avoid spurious output
    if grep -q "$@"; then
        STATE="true"
    else
        STATE="false"
    fi
}

possibleErrors=("string1 string1 string1" "string2 string2 string2")

for checkError in ${possibleErrors[*]}
do
    # Edit: fixed quotes; pass two quoted arguments
    grepCheck "${possibleErrors[$checkError]}" "$LOG"
done
```

If you simply care whether any of these strings matched, it would be simpler to pass them all to `grep` in one go.

```
regex=$(IFS='|'; echo "${possibleErrors[*]}")
grep -Eq "$regex" "$LOG"
```

Comment: I think you want to use egrep in the second example with '|' ?

Comment: @Bitdiot Meh, I was trying to wiggle around that, but you're right, it's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a little funny.  grep usually wants a regular expression and a file to look for the expression.  However, in your example, grepCheck is given an error string to-find, and a log to look for it.

Here you have:

```
if grep $1 ; then
```

Because $1 is unquoted, the shell expands this to grep string1 string1 string1.  So grep wants to look for string1 in the two files called string1 and string1 (basically the same two files.).

I think you want the following:

```
function grepCheck () {
    needle=$1
    haystack=$2
    if [[ -n $(grep "$needle" "$haystack") ]] ; then
        STATE="true"     # Error found
    else
        STATE="false"
    fi }
```

Then in your calling code:

```
grepCheck "${possibleErrors[$checkError]}" $LOG
```

Notice the change in quoting.

Comment: That's a Useless Use of `[[`.  `grep` tells you perfectly well whether or not it succeeded just by itself, and the OP's code has this part exactly right.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for correcting my bad habit.  Let me change that.  If you don't mind.

Comment: Hey triplee.  I changed it back to the original.  The reason is, and I just remembered, he may not want to see the results of the grep, but to set the flags.

Comment: Use `grep -q` for that.  See my answer.

Comment: Wow, that's nice.  I didn't know of the -q option.  Thanks.

Comment: I ofcourse simplified my example just so I could understand what I'm doing wrong. But thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like:

`...
for checkError in seq 0 $((${#possibleErrors[*]} - 1))
...`

But this is also a useless use of an array:

`for error in "string1 string1 string1" "string2 string2 string2"; do
  grepCheck "$error" "$LOG"
done`