# How to interate through command line arguments saved in a variable?

Tags: bash, iteration, command-line-arguments

At some point in my script I need to save value of all command line
arguments in a variable (after some `shift`ing), it looks like this:

```
foo="$@"
```

Now I need to interate through the arguments from `foo` variable, but it
seems to be quite hard to do it properly if there are arguments containing
write space. If I write

```
for i in "$foo"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Everything is printed on one line, indicating that `for` thinks there is
only one argument. On the other hand:

```
for i in $foo
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

seems to do the right thing, but it fails too when there are arguments
containing write space:

```
$ my_script one two "three four"
one
two
three
four
```

In this example `three` and `four` should be printed on the same line.

How to iterate though arguments saved in a variable properly?

Comment: Related: [How to iterate over list which contains whitespaces in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14587972/1983854)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use bash arrays:

```
foo=("$@")

for i in "${foo[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

This also allows you to address individual arguments as `${foo[0]}`, `${foo[1]}`, and so forth, up to `${#foo[@]}`, which is the length of the array.

Note that arrays are bash-specific (not part of the POSIX shell language).

Comment: Great. The only problem is that it's bash specific. But it's not critical for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark, you tagged your question with bash, so don't be surprised to get bash answers.

Comment: @glennjackman, good point. Next time I will tag it with [shell] too ;-)

Comment: @Mark The implementation of something vaguely array-ish in POSIX shell that is not painful to both write and to use is, as far as I'm aware, an unsolved problem. It'll generally involve something like `eval set -- "$array"` to expand the array into the positional variables, and doing that requires meticulous quoting with special care given to single quotes within the arguments. If you find yourself in a position where you need it and can't rely on bash, consider using another programming language. Perl comes to mind -- boxes that don't have it are few and far between these days.