# Bash Looping 2 Arrays with whitespaces in variables

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, for-loop

I'm working on a script to find the disk usage of directories on a server.
I need to handle folders with spaces in the name.

I'm having trouble using a for loop to run through each variable with spaces, as it will see them as two separate vars.

#### Current Snippet:

```
scandest="/root/*"
usedest="/root/fileusage/diskusage"

diskusage=$(du -sh $scandest > $usedest)

dir=($(cat $usedest|cut -f2|cut -c7-))
storage=($(cat $usedest|cut -f1))

echo "${dir[@]}"
```

This will output the following:

```
anaconda-ks.cfg
file test
fileusage
install.log
install.log.syslog
```

The file "file test" will get split once run through my loop.

So If I can echo this with quotes around each variable - then I'll be able to continue. Or if someone has a better idea for what I'm trying to achieve, I'm all ears!

Thank you

#### Edit 2

Loop is containing 2 arrays *dir* and *storage*

```
for ((i=0;i<${#dir[@]};i++)); do
echo "${dir[$i]}" -- "${storage[$i]}"
done
```

Which in turn outputs:

```
anaconda-ks.cfg -- 4.0K
file -- 0
test -- 16K
fileusage -- 12K
install.log -- 4.0K
install.log.syslog --
```

As you can see "file test" is treated as two variables.

Comment: note this code has some errors in it. Paste it in http://www.shellcheck.net/ to clean them (hint: `diskusage= du -sh...` is wrong, you probably want to say `diskusage=$(du -sh $scandtest ...)`)

Comment: Also, to loop over a list that contains spaces you better use `${var[@]}` as seen in [How to iterate over list which contains whitespaces in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14588210/1983854). In your case, `for result in ...`. Note also that there is no need to store the data in a file, since outputting to a variable suffices.

Comment: `file test` is treated as two variables because the shell cannot distinguish between whitespace that separates files and whitespace that is part of a file name in the output of your command substitution. Use `while` with `read` as suggested by Tom Fenech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `du -0` option to null terminate output from `du` and use this `while` loop to iterate:

```
while read -d '' -r size name; do
    printf "%s -> %s\n" "$size" "$name"
done < <(du -sh -0 /root/*)
```

This will avoid creation of temporary file and use of multiple error prone `cut` commands.

Comment: This is tested and working code with `gnu du`. What is your `du` version? Test with `du --version` command

Comment: Output of du --version `du (GNU coreutils) 8.4`

Comment: Yes that is what I also have. Does `du -sh -0 /root/*` show you any output?

Comment: Aha! I have made a separate script and this is working! Well not completely - but I think I'll be able to create what I need with it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your array has been populated correctly, your loop should simply be:

```
for d in "${dir[@]}"; do
    # do something with "$d", e.g.
    echo "$d"
done
```

Use double quotes around the array expansion at the top of the loop and remember to quote the loop variable when you use it.

However, it looks like `$dir` isn't an array in your example.

I would suggest changing your code to this:

```
while read -r junk dir rest; do
    d=${dir:6}
    # use "$d" here
done < /root/fileusage/diskusage
```

This reads each line of your file, splitting into three variables. The second one, `$dir`, contains the second field, which should be equivalent to the output of `cut -f2`. `${dir:6}` removes the first 6 characters from the variable.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My for loop contains 2 Arrays. Here is how I'm doing it: `for((i=0;i<${#storage[@]};i++)); do echo "${dir[$i]}" - "${storage[$i]}" done`

Comment: I'm continuing my testing, and will update all once figured out.

Comment: When I run this it will chop off everything after a space. As well I'm having difficulty working it into a loop with two arrays. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: You need to edit your question to show us the minimal example that we can use to reproduce your problem. At the moment, it's not clear what your starting point is.

Comment: I've updated the question to my latest script. Thanks for your continued assistance.