# How to have a bash variable that contains whitespace?

Tags: bash

So I'm learning today that Bash is all sorts of weird.

I'm trying to set up a variable that goes to a folder on my Mac (Bash 3.2)

```
FOLDER=".../Application Support/..."
```

But...

Bash will choke and say something like:

```
.../Application: No such file or directory
```

It will still choke if I use `{}`

```
{.../Application: No such file or directory
```

How can I get access to this folder via Bash?!

Comment: Referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587972/how-to-iterate-over-list-which-contains-whitespaces-in-bash

Comment: How are you trying to reference `FOLDER` in your script when you use it to open a file or a directory?

Comment: @denis_lor — it's actually not a script. It's in my `.bash_profile` and I'm trying to make a shortcut to get to it.

Comment: You put this as an example in your `.bash_profile`: `alias godesktop='cd ~/Desktop/'` and then do a `source .bash_profile` to refresh the state. And then in terminal type `godesktop`

Comment: an example with whitespace would be `alias godesktop='cd ~/Desktop/Application\ Support'`

Comment: I got it :) Thank you. Made it with variable too — `alias go...='cd "$VAR_NAME"'`

Comment: And in case you need to type `cd` yourself, then put in bash_profile only `FOLDER='Desktop/Application Support'` and call it in terminal like this: `cd "${FOLDER}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208328/discussion-between-denis-lor-and-ovatsug25).